# Prove that $11^{2n}+5^{2n+1}-6$ is divisible with $24$ for $n∈ℤ^+$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove that $11^{2n}+5^{2n+1}-6$ is divisible with $24$ for $n∈ℤ^+$

I've been trying to solve it by using modulo;
$11^{2n}+5^{2n+1}-6≡ (11^2 mod24)^n + 5*(5^2mod24)^n-6 = 1^n + (5*1^n)-6 = 0$

Is this the right way to tackle the problem? I am not certain if I am placing the "$mod$" marks at the right places.

Comment: $5^{2n+1} = 5 \mod{24}$

Comment: You can use `\pmod` or `\bmod` or just `\mod`: $2\pmod{3}, 2\bmod{3}, 2\mod 3$.

Comment: $5^{2n+1}\equiv5\ (mod\ 24)$ and $11^{2n}\equiv1\ (mod\ 24)$. $5+1-6=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$11^{2n}+5^{2n+1}-6=(5\cdot24+1)^n+5(24+1)^n-6\equiv 1+5-6\equiv0\pmod{24}$$